# 'v4l2' is not a suitable output format - why does this error appear?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-encoding, v4l2, nixos

I have created following script I've been using on Arch Linux to stream the camera feed to OBS

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 max_buffer=2

gphoto2 \
    --stdout \
    --set-config viewfinder=1 \
    --capture-movie |
    ffmpeg \
        -i - \
        -vcodec copy \
        -threads 1 \
        -f v4l2 \
        "/dev/$(ls -1 /sys/devices/virtual/video4linux)"
```

Since I've switched to NixOS, it stopped working with following error.

```
q --enable-libzimg --enable-zlib --disable-vulkan --disable-libglslang --disable-libsmbclient --disable-debug --enable-optimizations --disable-extra-warnings --disable-stripping
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Capturing preview frames as movie to 'stdout'. Press Ctrl-C to abort.
[mjpeg @ 0xe08300] Format mjpeg detected only with low score of 25, misdetection possible!
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1024x576, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn
[NULL @ 0xe0af80] Requested output format 'v4l2' is not a suitable output format
/dev/video0: Invalid argument
```

I've tried to capture frame using gphoto2 and it successfully captures one frame.

```shell
gphoto2 --capture-movie=1
```

Applications

```shell
❯ nixos-version
23.05.2664.9034b46dc4c7 (Stoat)

❯ gphoto2 --version
gphoto2 2.5.28

❯ ffmpeg --version
ffmpeg version 5.1.3
```

```
  boot.kernelModules = [ "v4l2loopback" ];
  boot.extraModulePackages = [ pkgs.linuxPackages.v4l2loopback ];
```

Why does it say v4l2 is not suitable?

Comment: Start by upgrading your software. ffmpeg is definitely outdated as 6 exists. Install the `full` version too for the biggest coverage: https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&show=ffmpeg_6-full&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=ffmpeg

Comment: If that doesn't help, show the whole output of `ffmpeg` and only the `v4l2` part of `ffmpeg -formats` in the question.

Comment: @Destroy666 worked. Thanks. Do you want to add this an answer

Comment: @Destroy666 Patch 5.1.3 was technically released after 6.0

Comment: @FFmpegEnthusiast nothing new - older major versions can get newer minor bugfixes than some nwer major versions. But when it comes to wanting more features, you have to go for newer.

Comment: @Destroy666 You're correct but I was saying technically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remember to always keep your software up-to-date, unless you require a specific version for a known reason like a bug in a newer one. ffmpeg is on version `6.x` right now and NixOS has built [packages](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=ffmpeg_6) for it.

Secondly, for ffmpeg, it's always good to install the `full` build. One also [exists](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=23.05&show=ffmpeg_6-full&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=ffmpeg_6) for NixOS. You can be (almost) sure with that that you're not missing out on any optional dependencies, except for e.g. cases when they're only available for specific systems. Here `v4l2` is indeed optional, which can be seen in the [source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-23.05/pkgs/development/libraries/ffmpeg/generic.nix#L613) of the package.